# Open data on cyber bullying?

Tags: data-request

Do you have any sources of open data on cyber bullying?

Are there any U.S. government (federal, state or local) departments that provide this data?

Comment: Searching for [cyber bullying statistics](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cyber+bullying+statistics) seems to turn up some data, notably site [NoBullying.com](https://nobullying.com/), which calls itself *The world's authority on bullying*.